# Ida: How to locate a buffer variable on memory

Tags: buffer, memory-address, ida

I have an executable file that seems to be hitting a stack buffer overflow. I'm pretty sure I understand most of what's going on, but all I need to know is where the buffer is stored in memory. If I knew either its absolute address, or relative to EBP or any other register, I'd be golden.

I know Ida keeps track of strings and functions, but is there any way I can locate a buffer or similar variables? Is there at least a way I can get some kind of clue?

I have been able to supply arguments to the program, but I have no idea how these arguments relate to the buffer if at all. Again, it wouldn't be difficult if I could locate where these variables are going.

I'm fairly new to Ida, so I feel like this shouldn't be that difficult to accomplish, I'm just missing some key piece of information.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I really don't know, and frankly I'd really like an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, as no one is answering my question, I might as well provide what I found out as the best possible answer myself.

**1) Understand how assembly writes to memory**

In x86 processors, an assembly instruction to write one byte to memory will look something like this:

```
MOV Ptr Byte [ECX], EAX
```

In this example, the contents of register EAX is written to the memory location specified by the contents of ECX. Using [Immunity](http://debugger.immunityinc.com/ID_register.py), set a breakpoint at this kind of instruction. As soon as the program hits this line, for instance, check the contents of ECX and look up the memory dump at that location. That should be where the buffer is being written to.

**2) Understand how memory is being stored**

In the memory window of Immunity, each memory dump corresponds to allocated space created during runtime. If ASLR is disabled (you can forcefully disable it using [EMET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Mitigation_Experience_Toolkit)), you can simply run the program, then search for the memory after the fact. If ASLR is enabled, try to find out what kind of memory it is being written to each re-run, then try to deduce which memory dump is being written to. After making your deduction, set a breakpoint in the memory dump, set to be triggered as soon as anything is written or read from it.

It would have killed you to say as many words as this? hm?